# Div height not consistent based on position

Tags: html, css

I have folowing demo. These 2 lines should look equal in height, but one is thicker. All this depends on its top position. If I change its top position by 1px it may become "normal" looking again. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

```css
.a {

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.line {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: cannot reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: It happens in chrome for me. It could be related to browser zoom but my chrome is at 100% zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I can see it on my screen. I think, from looking at the inspector that it's when the calculated height is a few fractions of a pixel out that it sometimes renders as 2 physical pixels high. Moving the height up and down by 1px causes it to behave as desired.

If you just want a 1px solid line you can set the `height` to 0px and use `border-bottom` instead.

```css
.a {

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height:11px;
}

.line {
  width: 300px;
  height: 0px;
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 0px;
  background: none;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens on Firefox but not on Chrome I have no explanation for why. But the issue here is that the HTML and the Body have 0 heights. Make sure to give them heights. You can test this by forcing and making sure that the parent height has a value of more than 2px. Once I did this the problem is solved.

Comment: I tried adding height to ".a" but no difference.

Comment: Can you inspect .a and check if it already takes this height or it is forced by the body height bec the body height in your case is zero